# differentiate if a client is running OSX or Windows

Tags: javascript, php, user-agent

Is it possible to differentiate if a client is running OSX or Windows in any other way than checking `navigator.useragent` property? I am developing a web app limited to OS X users and useragents are somewhat unreliable.

Comment: Bear in mind that whatever method you choose to use to get this information, it can be manipulated by the end user as they're the ones ultimately in control of their browser.  So there will always be a (potentially non-trivial) way around such a check, and/or you risk blocking false positives as people that _are_ running on OSX may have chosen to not allow their browser to leak that information.

Answer (score 1):

Check

```
window.navigator.platform
```

window.navigator as a whole should have more data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [get_browser()](https://www.php.net/get_browser) **PHP function** to get the platform and other details.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't have access to much more data than the client itself.

Comment: hmm, I am trying to find by browscap.ini file. It looks like I don't even have it. If I don't have it, and I am a developer, than I guess others don't have it too.

Comment: Oh this seems to be a file on serverside. My apologies.

Comment: Yeah this file needs to be on server side.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all detail by using $_SERVER variable in php.